# Visio Services, the service shuts down on its own + Doesn't meet the requirements

Tags: visio

Good day.
Problem: The Visio service automatically turns off after (approximately) a day after the forced start from SP CMD. On the page next to the Visio Services line, an error is displayed: In the column, "meets the requirements" - Fix. When pressed and corrected, the service application does not start automatically.

[image]
Any ideas will help me.

Farm description:
Sharepoint 2016;
Type: App & Search
SQL 2014.

Customized according to many step by step instructions

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are attempting to start it on an Application + Search. Visio Service will only run on a server using a Custom, Web Front End, or Single Server Farm roles.

Note that Visio Services should only run on Front Ends to provide your end users with the best experience.

[Description of MinRole and associated services in SharePoint Servers 2016 and 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/administration/description-of-minrole-and-associated-services-in-sharepoint-server-2016)

[Role conversion using MinRole in SharePoint Servers 2016 and 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/administration/role-conversion-using-minrole-in-sharepoint-server-2016)

Comment: Thank you very much. I study aspects of the server role.
Let me know more from you. In my current configuration, will any of the following work: PerformancePoint; PoverView; power BI??

Comment: (I don't know how the management will decide on the role of the server. But in the near future I need to find a solution for the task of graphs. The client will provide data and I have to display it graphically and even with the ability to switch between indicators. (3 levels of nesting).
Maybe you have ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Alex, that sounds like a different question than the one you originally asked -- can you please post that as a new question? Your only option for starting Visio Services is to change the MinRole for the server in question.

Comment: ok. I will create. thank